# IOS NSString return statement

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstring

There is some code that I am using written by someone else that I have a question....

```
NSString *c = @"test";  // "Local" string
NSString *d = [NSString alloc]initWithString:@"test"]; // "Heap" string

const char *c = "test";
return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:c]; // ??
```

I am not sure what the return statement in this case is returning.  I would have written it something like...

```
return [NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:c];
```

or

```
return [NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:c]autorelease];
```

Why would the return statement be written like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:c]` returns an autoreleased object ..so its the same thing as `[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:c]autorelease]`  but from what i understand from documentation `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:c]` doesn't make a copy of the string..so its  faster

Comment: Ah, ok, I assume that much (return adds alloc autorelease) but just wanted to make sure.  So really the c has to be on the stack or static / global and the NSString object is alloc autorelease.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By convention stringWithUTF8String returns an already autoreleased string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is. If you're unsure about the return value of a method, check the documentation, and you'll have your answer

Comment: Ok, no problem.  Please point to the exact document and the exact line that has this and let me know how long it takes you to find it.  I am not that familiar with the IOS doc set and it takes almost not time here and other's can enjoy your clear answers.

Comment: "NSString" in google, first link. Then in the sidebar, expand "Class methods", and there it is

Comment: Fair enough, it was pretty quick, but the statement....Returns an NSString object initialized by copying the characters a given C array of UTF8-encoded bytes.....Does not mention the fact that the object is   treated differently on a return.  Maybe I am missing something here.  If an autoreleased object is returned it is not released at the end of the procedure.  Have not spent much time in IOS, so I guess this makes sense.